# Finding the threshold value in a given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-tree, coding-efficiency

Given a array, I have to find the maximum threshold value such that elements smaller than that in the array are multiplied by c1 and greater than that are multiplied c2.

Now the sum I get by adding all in the elements of the array should cross the value given by the user.

I thought of using a BST. I couldn't think of any idea. Can you help me in an efficient algorithm?

Example:
400, 500, 600 
c1= 0.05 c2= 0.1
Value:125

Here, the threshold value is 500. 
(500+600)*0.1 + 400*0.05 = 130

Answer (score 0):

If elements are positive (or at least cumulative sums are monotone), you can apply binary search:

Calculate cumulative sums in auxilliary array `Sums[]`

With binary search find the smallest index `k` (like `std::lower_bound` in C++ STL)  that

```
 Sums[k] * c1 + (OverallSum - Sums[k]) * c2 >= Value
 or 
 Sums[k]  >= (Value - OverallSum * c2) / (c1 - c2)
```

Note that the first stage takes O(n) time, so for one-time task 
you can use simple linear searching at the second stage.

But if you reuse the same array with different `Value`'s - binary search will more effective.

Here

```
Sums = [400, 900, 1500]
(Value - OverallSum * c2) / (c1 - c2) = 
   (125 - 1500 * 0.1) / (0.05-0.1) = 
      -25 / -0.05 = 500

 The first value in Sums[] > 500 is 900, so index is 1, value is 500
```